# Запрос Activerecord Yii2

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица 
Cashboxes(
  id,
  article_id,
  sum,
)

Как при помощи ActiveRecord составить запрос, согласно которому я могу сгруппировать все записи по article_id и посчитать по каждой группе сумму?

Пробую так:

```
$cashboxes = Cashboxes::find()
            ->select(['article_id', 'sum'])
            ->groupBy('article_id')
            ->all();
```

Но в этом случае вместо общей суммы по всей группе article_id, выводится первая запись в колонке sum.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень хорошо называть поля служебными словами (sum). Чтобы получить сумму по каждой группе, необходимо суммировать все значения в этой группе:

```
$cashboxes = Cashboxes::find()
        ->select(['article_id', 'SUM(sum) AS sum'])
        ->groupBy('article_id')
        ->all();
```